# How can I search for a string in a log and only fail if I find it in Hudson?

Tags: hudson, grep

My build and deploy step creates some logs.  I would like to search the logs for and fail the build if I see certain strings.

A good log looks like

```
log stuff
step 1: SUCCESS
step 2: SUCCESS
```

A log with failures would look like

```
log stuff
step 1: SUCCESS
step 2: FAIL
```

My check is

```
grep FAIL /path/to/build.log
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  exit 1
fi
```

I've also tried

```
RESULT=`grep FAIL /path/to/build.log`
if [ -n "$RESULT" ]; then
  exit 1
fi
```

and various ways of piping in the file.

Hudson is failing the build on grep not returning anything.  So is there a better way to search for the string?  Is there a way to have grep not returning anything not exit the script right there?

Version Stuff:
* Hudson 1.355

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the hudson documentation for a shell command:

> By default, the shell will be invoked with the "-ex" option. So all of the commands are   printed before being executed, and the build is considered a failure if any of the commands exits with a non-zero exit code. Again, add the #!/bin/... line to change this behavior.

So, try adding a #!/bin/sh line and see what it does?

Comment: I'm glad you posted this. I have been using a really yucky workaround for this problem. I'm going to give this a try.